# Cleaner way to see if function is defined

Tags: javascript

Is there an easier way to check if a javascript function has already been called and is active besides what I have below, or is what I have below already optimized...

```
    var isDefined = function(func) {
       if(func !== undefined)
       {
          return true;
       }
       else
       {
          return false;
       }
     }
```

Comment: Your question wording is ambiguous.  Do you want to see if a function is defined or if it has already been called/invoked?

Comment: I'm hoping to clarify what you mean here, because "has already been called" sounds very unrelated to "is active". I'm not actually sure what "is active" means. Are you trying to prevent multiple threads from accessing it or something? Apart from your `isDefined` function, can you show how you would intend to use it?

Comment: You cannot tell if a function has been called purely from its name.  You can tell if the function is present in the current scope and is callable with `if (typeof func === "function")`, but not if it has already been called.

Comment: What I want to do is find out if the function has been called already, that way I can ensure there wont be any double up's on some functions that could possibly cause unexpected results.

Comment: the problem is, you check inside the function if the function is called. but when checked, the function must be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does nothing to retain memory of a function having already been called. You can put a Boolean var flag outside of it, set it to true inside, and ensure its scope doesn't leak by putting it inside an IIFE, which may give you what you want.

If what you're doing is related to click/event listening, you may want to use something like JQuery's `$.once()`, which adds an event listener that removes itself after occurring once.

Answer (score -1):

```
var isDefined = function(func) {
     return (func !== undefined);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve any particular problem.  It's shorthand for what the OP already has.

Comment: though I didn't downvote, this edit is not much of an improvement.  What if we had previously done `func = "hello world!"`?  You should at least return (typeof func === 'function')

Comment: I thought the op wanted an optimized version of his code.